# Неизвестные вотермарки в верстке

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, вёрстка

Недавно фронтенд-разработчик сдал верстку сайта на проверку, проблема заключается в том, что в рандомных местах появляются вотермарки такого вида [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В текстовых редакторах они не отображаются, PHP storm их не видит, но удалить может (нужно поставить курсор перед закрывающим тегом элемента, где стоит вотермарк, и нажать Backspace) - тем не менее, если удалить вотермарк в одном элементе, появится новый в другом.

Скорее всего проблема в каком-либо js плагине, но во фронтенде я не очень силён, а разработчик, который сдал эту верстку, говорит "я хз", поэтому ищу решение здесь, мало ли кто-нибудь из Вас сталкивался конкретно с таким вотермарком и знает способ, как убрать этот код или какой плагин может его вызывать? Может быть проблема и не в JS вовсе (так как я не очень понимаю, как JS может перезаписывать статические файлы), с этим я сталкиваюсь впервые

Comment: А как мы должны понять проблему без кода и т.д.?

Comment: @And В данном случае нужно скидывать весь репозиторий? я рассчитываю на то, что кто-то сталкивался с чем-то подобным.

Comment: К сожалению, телепатов тут нет. Это может быть чем угодно, вплоть до плагинов браузера или еще чего-нибудь, в коде например.

Comment: вы бы в шторме, или другом редакторе, шрифт включили такой же как на вэб странице да посмотрели что и где.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45822037/6817117

Comment: @KAGGDesign спасибо!

Comment: @teran спасибо за совет